# Laravel email service provider : Object of class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to send email using laravel and getting this strange error. `Object of class DateTimeImmutable could not be converted to string`

I am not using date or something anywhere. Here is the code for sending email

```
 $paymentInfo = $this->paymentQuery->singupDataForInvoice($id);
    Mail::to([$paymentInfo->playerOne->email,$paymentInfo->playerTwo->email])->bcc(['one@gmail.com', 'two@gmail.com', 'three@dgmail.com'])->send(new Invoice($paymentInfo));
    return 'done';
```

I am getting error in `vendor/inspector-apm/inspector-laravel/src/Providers/EmailServiceProvider.php:67`

More info from error stack

```
protected function getSegmentKey($message)

{

    // The methods used to generate the hash are consistent across Laravel versions up to v9.

    return sha1(json_encode($message->getTo()).$message->getSubject().$message->getDate());

}
```

This code coming from an inspector plugin

Not sure what's happening. it was working before.

Comment: Looks like your code try to use some DateTimeImmutable filed as a string. 
I think we need more code or more stack trace to investigate. Can you show singupDataForInvoice method and Invoice entity?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Object+of+class+could+not+be+converted+to+string -- it's not a strange error, I'd say. Please extract a [mcve] and provide that here.

Comment: Ok I see now, I use inspector plugin. And that plugin trying to use date like this `protected function getSegmentKey($message)

    {

        // The methods used to generate the hash are consistent across Laravel versions up to v9.

        return sha1(json_encode($message->getTo()).$message->getSubject().$message->getDate());

    }`

Comment: Ok I removed that package and its solved now